# Error with JSON API Framework

Tags: c#, json, jsonapiframework

I have a .NET solution containing a DAL project with the configuration for my entities and a Web API Project containing all my entities which are imported from SQL Server and my controllers are implemented.
When I run the project I have this error (comment is one of the entities which has one-to-many relationship with 2 other entities):

> An exception of type
>   'JsonApiFramework.ServiceModel.ServiceModelException' occurred in
>   JsonApiFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information:
>   JsonApiFramework.ServiceModel.Internal.ResourceType [clrType=Comment]
>   has missing ResourceIdentityInfo metadata. Ensure metadata is
>   configured correctly for the respective domain/schema.

[image]

Comment: looks like you use JSONAPI.NET. Did you check the documentation on how to serialize relationships?

Comment: Hi Alexander, sorry for the delay. Yes I checked the documentation but i did not find any reliable answer for my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. To work efficiently with Json API, the id of every entity should be named simply `id`. My Entity named `Business` had an id named `idBus`. So when I changed the name `idBus` to `id`, it all worked.

I hope this can help anybody.

Comment: You could probably also use **EntityName**Id

Comment: This information is incomplete. This problem can also be generated by using inheritance.  [More information](https://github.com/scott-mcdonald/JsonApiFramework/issues/75)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following aswell (if you don't wan't to change your id names):

```
public class BusinessConfiguration : ResourceTypeBuilder<Business>
{
    public BusinessConfiguration()
    {
        this.ResourceIdentity(x => x.idBus).SetApiType("business");

    }
}
```